# Cannot create formula using lookup object?

Tags: formula-field, custom-field, product2

I just modified The standard salesforce object [Product2](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_product2.htm)
To include a custom property -  a checkbox.

I want to map this property out to the cart it belongs to.
the way a product is associated to to a cart as follows.

```
One Cart contains 0 or multiple CartItems.
Each CartItem References one Product
```

[Cart](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_webcart.htm), [CartItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_cartitem.htm?q=CartItem) are also standard Salesforce objects.

I cannot access product nor its properties via a formula even though they are related via lookup?

Is there some limitations with Formulas and lookups that does not allow me to create one that is referenced via a lookup, or what?

Comment: So a formula on `CartItem` that looks like `Product2.MyCustom_Property__c` does not work?

Comment: it does not appear as an field option I can select...

Comment: does the sysad have FLS on `Cart.Product2Id` as well as the new `Product2.MyCustom_Property__c`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formulas can reference data from *higher* in a hierarchy, but not *lower*.
You can reference data on a parent record, a grandparent, etc... going up to a maximum of 5 levels.
You cannot reference child records at all.

So you cannot use a formula to go from a Cart (parent) to its CartItems (child). If you have a formula on CartItem, you would be able to reference your new field on Product2 (because Product2 is a *parent* of CartItem).

Getting data from CartItem to Cart is where you would use a rollup summary field, the DLRS tool, a flow, or a trigger.

Comment: I am not sure i understand the concept of parent and children.  U are saying that a psrrent can only use it grandparents as references for a formular, does that mean that a product can look up the cart it is put into, but the not the other way around?

Comment: Anyway i can make a field dependen on the child Product it contains?

Comment: It turns out it seem to be related to how salesforce data is modelled in general -  everything is related in one to many, so a parent will never be able relate to a specific child, as it has many, but a child can always relate to its parent because there is always one of them.